# Pattern continued

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following pattern: 
$$\frac{3^{2/401}}{3^{2/401} +3}+\frac{3^{4/401 }}{3^{4/401} +3}+\frac{3^{6/401}}{3^{6/401} +3}+\frac{3^{8/401}}{3^{8/401} +3}$$

what will the result be if the pattern is continued $\;300\;$ times?

Comment: apologies for the poor text, I'm not sure what went wrong there it is meant to be 3 to the power of 2/401

Comment: Use base^{power} in LaTeX for exponentiation. 21^{76} is $21^{76}$.

Comment: ^ The {} are important...

Comment: thanks, im fairly new to LaTex

Comment: $n-$th term $$=\frac{3^{\frac{2,4,6,8\space n-th   }{401}}}{3^{\frac{2,4,6,8\space n-th   }{401}}+3}=\frac{3^{\frac{2n}{401}}}{3^{\frac{2n}{401}}+3}$$

Comment: I need the sum to the nth term

Comment: Your teacher seems to be a humorous man... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the sum to the nth term, you're looking at computing the sum of the first 300 terms:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{300}\left(\large\frac{3^{\frac{2k}{401}}}{3^{\frac{2k}{401}}+3}\right)$$

To sum to the nth term, you need to compute:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\large\frac{3^{\frac{2k}{401}}}{3^{\frac{2k}{401}}+3}\right)=
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\large\frac{3\cdot 3^{\frac{2k-1}{401}}}{3\cdot\left(3^{\frac{2k-1}{401}}+1\right)}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\large\frac{3^{\frac{2k-1}{401}}}{\left(3^{\frac{2k-1}{401}}+1\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt there is a simple closed form for this.  WolframAlpha only returns ([query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28k%20=%201%20to%20300%29,%20%283%5E%282k/401%29%29/%283%5E%282k/401%29%2b3%29)) the decimal approximation: $130.6386445...$

Also, the [inverse symbolic lookup calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) doesn't find anything...